# printing/writing horizontally/vertically

Tags: python

I have code that successfully retrieves a column of values from a file. When I attempt to write them into a file, it appears as a successive line like:

```
0.000000.000000.000000.000000.000000.000000.000000.000000.000000.000000.000
```

I would prefer that it print out in a list like:

```
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
```

The weird thing is that when I put in a

```
print(parts[1])
```

It prints out in a list (desired output) in the terminal window! Anybody know why this inconsistency would happen and how I can fix it to get desired output in my output file? The code is below:

```
with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
                for line in g:
                    parts = line.split()
                    if len(parts) > 1:
                        print(parts[1])
                        f.write(parts[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to write on the file a new line try

```
f.write('\n')
```

after the `f.write(parts[1])`

Comment: I didn't think the fix would be so simple! this worked perfectly! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the 2nd part of your question without testing it myself, but if you'd like to print in a column format you could try

```
>>> x = ['apples', 'bananas', 'grapes']
>>> print "\n".join(x)
apples
bananas
grapes
```

or in your case `x` would equal `parts`